# Thymeleaf decimal formatting options at user generated content

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to parse and process a user generated content in the backend with thyme leaf.
Therefore we have done the following:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1")
@Slf4j
public class MyController {

  @Autowired
  private TemplateEngine templateEngine;

  ... 
  
  @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK", response = DeliveryDTO.class)
  @PostMapping(path = "/{myId}/serve")
  public DeliveryDTO serve(
        @PathVariable String myId

  ) {
      ... // get myObj;
      html = templateEngine.process(myObj.getHtml(), myObj.getContext());
```

this works really fine. But now we have some parts of myObj which should get a default formatting. For example

myObj.getHtml() could deliver this:

```
<table>
   <tr th:each="item: ${ko}">
       <td>
           <a th:href="@{${URLBuilder.build(item)}}"><span th:text="${item.isin}"></span></a>.     
      </td>
      <td>
           <span th:text="${item.value1}"></span>
      </td>
      <td>
           <span th:text="${item.value2}"></span>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Now I want all occurrences of "item.value1" to be formatted with two decimals and "item.value2" with three decimals. I could add that to the html-template, but as this is some kind of user content I would prefer to iterate over all occurrences and add a decimal formatting option.
Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Cheers Maik

Comment: Can you also add the controller?

Comment: I just updated the question

Comment: It is still not clear but from what I can see this has nothing to do with Thymeleaf. You have two options - either format the value before passing it to the template or use JavaScript to format it.

Comment: The data is persisted in the database, so I don't have the possibility to do sth with JavaScript. As the template processing is somehow finding all occurences of template variables and formatting it itself there must be some kind of way to get all variables without manually parsing the html. TemplateEngine is actually an injected Thymeleaf class
Somehow I should be able to manipulate these variable formatting

Comment: That is what JavaScript is for. It can manipulate how things *appear*.

Comment: yes, I know. But the display part is not in our full control :)
But meanwhile I am getting closer. the Context is a thymeLeaf context. It seems the variables are inside there. I am investigating further.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `@NumberFormat` annotation on the fields in your DTO.
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#format-annotations-api

If that's not possible, thymeleaf also has some [formatting options](https://frontbackend.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-utility-methods-for-numbers)

Comment: But I don't have a DTO here. All I have is a field named "html" which is a string containing all the thymeleaf syntax.

Comment: What @EpicMartijn mentioned in his link to Thymeleaf formatters seems to be directly relevant to your question. But when you say _"the display part is not in our full control"_, what does that mean? Does it mean you cannot edit the Thymeleaf template you show in your question? Can you not use something like this: `${#numbers.formatDecimal(item.value1, 3, 2)}`? If not, then why not format the data in Java before you send it to the template? Do either of those help?

Comment: We will have "business" users, who will use the frontend. We could somehow implement a feature to add this directly to the template in the editor but the better way would be if we control this from the backend. Then business only edits the template with minimalistic thymeleaf syntax which is not easily understandable for business guys. So we want to keep up only with the variable names and control from the backend. I now managed to get it working using the thymeleaf context and preparing the variables there using java code formatting. Not as I wished to accomplish this, but ok for now :)

Comment: And for the control of JavaScript. When we output the rendered template this may happen on several webpages which use our JS to fetch the rendered html from our server. So if all works fine we maybe could finally format it. But doing this server side is the better approach as we intent to not only print this on webpages but also in apps and then we have no control at all...